# Tension in string connecting an axis of rotation with a pulley and a mass

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, string

I have a system that is similar to the classic system where you have a mass on a table connected with string to a pulley that is once again connected to a mass. [Here is a Youtube video with a figure of the situation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qu46xL4KPvU&t=20s&ab_channel=MichelvanBiezen).

However, instead of the mass on the table the string connects to an axis with a rotating disk on top. I need to find the moment of inertia of this rotating disk, however I am unable to set up all the forces as I am not sure what the tension in the string connecting the disk with the pulley is. I know that it must be related to the pulley because the pulley is not massless, perhaps the tension minus the torque?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've simply replaced a translating object with a rotating one, the only change you should need to make to the solution from the video is to use the rotational version of Newton's second law for the disk, $\tau_{net} = I\alpha$, instead of the linear version, $F_{net} = ma$.  On the disk, the only force with a non-zero lever arm is the tension $T_1$.  So you have

$R_{disk}T_1 = I_{disk}\alpha = I_{disk}\frac{a}{R_{disk}} = \frac12 M_{disk}{R_{disk}}^2 \frac{a}{R_{disk}} = \frac12 M_{disk}R_{disk}a \\ \rightarrow T_1 = \frac12 M_{disk} a$

Then you need to algebraically combine that with the equations of the pulley and the block, which will be the same as the video.  But since you're interested in the disk instead of the acceleration, you would need to be *given* the value of acceleration, so that you could solve for $M_{disk}$.  Then you would also need to be given $R_{disk}$ so you could calculate $I_{disk} = \frac12 M_{disk} {R_{disk}}^2$.  (By the way, this formula for $I_{disk}$ assumes the disk has uniform mass density, which they usually do in these problems.)

Comment: Thank you, I was actually given a distance travelled under a certain time, so I did get the acceleration. However, the mass I get is much too large. What I found was that $M_{disk} = \frac{2}{a} (m_{block} g - m_{block} a - 1/2m_{pulley}a)$ and I cannot find any mistakes while solving the system of equations

Comment: I get the same formula (though remember to use \frac12 instead of 1/2 so it's clear).  You can rewrite it as $M_{disk} = 2 m_{block} \frac{g-a}{a} - m_{pulley}$, and if you think about that formula it generally makes sense, because a small acceleration implies the disk was quite massive, thus retarding the system.  So all I can say is double check your acceleration calculation, and make sure you use the moment of inertia formula at the end...